# Even perfect number that is also a sum of two cubes

Tags: proof-explanation, perfect-numbers

In 2010, Gallardo proved that the only even perfect number that is also a sum of two cubes is $28$. [Here](https://www.academia.edu/10938048/On_a_remark_of_Makowski_about_perfect_numbers) is a link to his proof (see the second page). The first part goes roughly as follows:

Let $N$ be an even perfect number. Assume that $N=x^3+a^3=(x+a)(x^2-xa+a^2)$. Note that $x$ and $a$ have the same parity. Consider the case $x+a<x^2-xa+a^2$. By the [Euclid–Euler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem), it follows that $N=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$, where $2^p-1$ is a Mersenne prime. Thus, $x+a=2^{p-1}$ and $x^2-xa+a^2=2^p-1$.

This is the step I don't understand. I get that $2^p-1>2^{p-1}$, so $2^p-1$ must be a factor of $x^2-xa+a^2$. But I don't see why all of $2^{p-1}$ has to be a factor of $x+a$. Why can't we have, say, $x+a=2^{p-2}$ and $x^2-xa+a^2=2(2^p-1)$?

Comment: It seems like a way to rephrase what you're asking is, why do x and a both have to be odd (as opposed to both being even).  Is that something you've thought about?

Comment: @CJD Yes, but it doesn't make sense to me. If we know that both integers are odd, then we must have $x^2-xa+a^2=2^p-1$, so we don't need to assume the inequality. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've stared at it without success.  Good luck!

Comment: It's unfortunate the paper is requiring me lots of login steps. Any chance you can snapshot the statement of the theorem?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Try this link: https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0013-6018&vol=65&iss=3&rank=4

Comment: At the very least, the statement is unobvious enough that the paper should have said more...

Comment: @Anonymous-agroup, I have not yet looked at the paper, but perhaps Gallardo makes the assumption $\gcd(x+a, x^2 - xa + a^2)=1$ (and later, proves that assumption)?